# Como obtener rango en una tabla en base al nombre inicial en vba?

Tags: vba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento saber es como obtener el rango que pertenece a la persona en cuestion, por ejemplo si el nombre cambia de Ivonne a Damaris, este tome el rango desde que empezo Ivonne hasta donde termino de la columna "AH" ya he buscado en otros foros pero no logro idear como solucionarlo, ya tengo donde me calcula la diferencia entre horarios.

Espero y me puedan ayudar, disculpen la imagen se que no se debe publicar a menos de que sea necesario.

Comment: si intentas grabar una macro, para hacer lo que necesitas, creo te dará algo como, `Range("B4").Select`
`Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select`

Comment: Pero ¿qué quieres hacer? Poner el nombre/ID de una persona y que te diga el rango? ¿Necesitas recorrer la hoja y hacer operaciones dentro de un determinado rango? ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?. Pon por aquí lo que tengas hecho para ver qué estás intentando hacer.